# Getting valued of am/pm from calendar object in case of blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry, calendar

i need to get the value of am/pm depending on the time set so i do this...

calendarobject.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

but this always returns 0 weather the system time is am/pm...

can any one tell me why this is happening..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was my mistake i was not setting the Hours_of_day value of the calendar object and hence the am_pm value was 0 always...